# How can I make generic View only accept POST or GET

Tags: django, django-views

```
class CustomerInfoCheckView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # CustomerInfoForm by ajax request
        if request.is_ajax():
            form = CustomerInfoForm(
                request.POST,
            )

            if form.is_valid():
                return JsonResponse(
                    data={
                        "valid": True,
                    }
                )
            else:
                return JsonResponse(
                    data={
                        "valid": False,
                        "errors": form.errors
                    }
                )
```

As you can see here, it only accept `POST` request.

I want to prevent user from accessing this `view` using `GET` requests.

I found `@require_http_methods` but it only support `function-based-view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its already done for you since you've only provided a `post` method

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views)

> Because Django’s URL resolver expects to send the request and associated arguments to a callable function, not a class, class-based views have an as_view() class method which returns a function that can be called when a request arrives for a URL matching the associated pattern. The function creates an instance of the class and calls its dispatch() method. dispatch looks at the request to determine whether it is a GET, POST, etc, and **relays the request to a matching method if one is defined, or raises HttpResponseNotAllowed if not**

Comment: But when I access this `view` through url, which is `GET` request, it shows just empty blank page, not `Page Not Found` something.

Comment: @user3595632 - Then that is a different issue, either you are handling responses yourself or some other code is at work

Comment: Do I have write code like this :   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Http404   ???

Comment: @user3595632 - "Its already done for you "..... "or raises HttpResponseNotAllowed if not"

Comment: @user3595632, Blank page means it is an empty httpresponse with 405 status_code.Its already working.You can check console

Answer (score 1):

You have to `implement get method in view` to handle get request. Else it will raise a `405 by default` that means method not implemented. A class based view inherited from `django.views.generic.view` have to override all methods that should be implemented. In your case code may looks like below.

```
class CustomerInfoCheckView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # CustomerInfoForm by ajax request
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = CustomerInfoForm(
            request.POST,
        )

        if form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse(
                data={
                    "valid": True,
                }
            )
        else:
            return JsonResponse(
                data={
                    "valid": False,
                    "errors": form.errors
                }
            )
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     raise Http404
```

You can raise 404, 405 or provide an `error response with 405 as status code` which will be more apt.